# Shrinking down mysql tables

Tags: mysql

can someone help me optimize/shrinking down this table so that looks displayed properly. i have tried the following commands without success.

optimize table ;

alter table  ROW_FORMAT = COMPRESSED;

```
| teamstats_id | Trade_id | home_team_corners | away_team_corners | home_team_cards                                                                                                  | away_team_cards                                                   |
+--------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|            1 |        1 |                 7 |                 4 | 74` Hong Jung-Woon, 94` Kim Woo-Seok                                                                             | NONE                                                              |
|            2 |        2 |                 3 |                 1 | 39` Suchy                                                                                                        | 53` Otavio, 73` Arnold, 93` Rousillon                             |
|            3 |        3 |                 5 |                 1 | 24` Kostic, 36` N`Dicka, 59` Silva An., 70` Ilsanker, 89` Kohr                                                   | 9` Elvedi                                                         |
|            4 |        4 |                 2 |                 6 | 66` Filipenko, 85` Nastic                                                                                        | 16` Koanda, 18` Cheboatev, 23` Tetrenko, 85` Koroev               |
|            5 |        5 |                 6 |                 9 | 4` Kuchinski, 9` Bordukov, 31` Bashilov, 47` Nechaev, 82` Yasukevich, 90` Yasukevich, 91` Solanovich, 94` Glebko | 17` Nazarenko, 25` Carioca, 29` Matveenko, 32` Cesar              |
|            6 |        6 |                 5 |                 6 | 22` Tikhonovsky, 67` Sedko, 72` Migunov                                                                          | 87` Vakulich                                                      |
|            7 |        7 |                 0 |                 0 | 40` RED Musayibov                                                                                                | NONE                                                              |
|            8 |        8 |                 2 |                 9 | 54` Moisander, 75` Friedl                                                                                        | 44` Bender                                                        |
|            9 |        9 |                 2 |                 9 | 54` Moisander, 75` Friedl                                                                                        | 44` Bender                                                        |
|           10 |       38 |                 0 |                 0 | NONE                                                                                                             | NONE                                                              |
|           11 |       39 |                 0 |                 0 | 10` Miil, 65` Kelder, 71` Opp, 80` Pajunurm, 86` Schjonnin-Larsen                                                | 51` Khomutov, 52` Subbotin, 59` Volkov, 82` Raudsepp, 93` Demitov |
|           12 |       40 |                 0 |                 0 | 38` Kauber, 87` Sinilaid                                                                                         | 58` Juhkam                                                        |
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by: "looks displayed properly"?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The dba sister site of SO is there for database admin related questions.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. And it is not a proper question, see how to form a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask